# Using arquillian with Google Guice 4.0 and JSF 2.2

Tags: wildfly, guice, jsf-2.2, jboss-arquillian, guice-3

I would like to use arquillian to do some more specific tests. The application is a jsf 2.2 web application which uses google guice 4.0 for DI.

In my web.xml i've defined a custom injection provider:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.injectionProvider</param-name>
        <param-value>com.custom.guice.GuiceInjectionProvider</param-value>
</context-param>
```

This works fine, except for the tests with arquillian. The tests are started with a wildfly-arquillian-container-managed adapter. The container starts-up, deploys and runs the testcase but the DI does not work.

I've also tried the arquillian-guice-extensions with @GuiceWebConfiguration, @GuiceConfiguration but nothing will work. Does anyone has experience with this case?

Comment: Is the injection not working in just the test cases or in the JSF components or both?

Comment: the injection does not work only in testcases which run with arquillian.

Comment: Are these client (`@RunAsClient`) tests or just normal tests? I've never tried this, but it seems like it could be tricky with a container not configured to use Guice.

Comment: No, they are normal tests.

Comment: My guess would be that CDI (Weld in WildFly's case) is getting in the way.